# React Transforming Server Response (adding extra field to an Object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, axios

I have a basic function that sends an axios GET request and sets the response (array of objects) in state.

```
getData(){
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data })
}
```

However I want to add an additional field to the object. How can I do this?

I figure something like:

```
getData(){
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => transformRes(response.data))
    .then(newResponse => this.setState({ data: newResponse })
}

transformRes(data){
  data.forEach(d => {
    // do something ??
  }
  // return newData ??
}
```

**mock example data (from Server)**

```
(2) [{...}, {...}]

0: {id: 1, name: 'foo'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'bar'}
```

**mock expected result (after transformRes)**

```
(2) [{...}, {...}]

0: {id: 1, name: 'foo', desc: 'active'} // added desc field.
1: {id: 1, name: 'bar', desc: 'active'} // added desc field.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add property in map function:

```
getData(){
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
       const res = response.data
       this.setState({ data: res.map(object => {
         return {...object, desc: 'active'}
        })})
    })
}
```

BTW `...` is spread operator and `...object` means every `key/value` in `object`.

Comment: You can use `Object.assign` instead of the spread operator if you don't have it available to you (you probably do given you're using react).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Nice explanation too. I had to make minor changes though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to map the old object to a new object. You're on the right track using `.forEach`

```
getData() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            var newData = response.map((data) => {
                data.desc = 'active'; //add your properties here
                return data;
            });
            this.setState({data: newData});
        });
}
```

Let me know if this won't work for your situation or you have questions.

Comment: Do I have to copy every field across? e.g. data.id = data.id ?

Comment: Actually, I messed up the code above. Please see the fixed version. And no you don't have to copy the existing fields, just the new ones.